# Left join operation performed in querydsl gives 'path expected error in querydsl'

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, querydsl

Here is my code:

```
QueryFactory.selectFrom(table1)
  .leftJoin(table2).on(table1.id.eq(table2.id)).fetch();
```

When I execute the below code in querydsl I get the following error:

> 08:08:54.866 ERROR o.h.h.i.a.ErrorCounter -  Path expected for join!
>       08:08:54.870 ERROR o.h.h.i.a.ErrorCounter -  Path expected for join!
>       antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:369)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]

Comment: In HQL, joins can only be done on associations between entities. If you want a join on something else, the only possibility is to make the join in the where clause