# MySQL query to QueryDsl query (Handling aliases)

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I am trying to translate the following MySQL query to QueryDSL

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TrainTable t1 LEFT JOIN TrainTable t2
ON (t1.Train = t2.Train AND t1.Time < t2.Time)
WHERE t2.Time IS NULL;
```

But I am stuck on how to handle the aliases on the `ON` part and the `WHERE` part.

This is what I had in mind:

```
QTrainTable  qt1 = new QTrainTable ("t1");

QTrainTable  qt2 = new QTrainTable ("t2");

List<TrainTable > fetch = query.select(qt1)
    .from(qt1)
    .leftJoin(qt2).on(qt1.institution.id.eq(qt2.institution.id).and(qt1.transDate.lt(qt2.transDate)))
    .where(qt2.transDate.isNull())
    .fetch();
```

but I get `Path expected for join` error. The error is thrown since there is no relationship between `qt1` and `qt2` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954610/left-join-operation-performed-in-querydsl-gives-path-expected-error-in-querydsl).

How can the MySQL query be re-written in QueryDSL?

Comment: `.leftJoin(qTrainTable 2)` isn't valid java. Please post actual source code.

Comment: @Jens Schauder, that's just a typo. Let me correct the typo in the question

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954610/left-join-operation-performed-in-querydsl-gives-path-expected-error-in-querydsl (it has an answer in the comments).

Comment: @Jens Schauder, thanks for the trouble of finding possible answers to the question. The link explains why `Path expected for join` error is experienced: i.e. there is no association between entities, but the main question is: how can the MySQL query be re-written in QueryDSL.Let me edit  the question to capture that

Comment: Can't you just use QueryDsl-SQL? https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-sql